# Uninitialized value warning at array length check

Tags: arrays, perl, dereference

I have the following code:

```
my @product_access = @{ $products->{ $PosDetails->{"SalProductRef"}->[$i]}
                      {DetAccess_tab} };

if ( @product_access == 1 )
{
    $revenue{ $products->{ $PosDetails->{"SalProductRef"}->[$i] }{DetFinanceCategory} }
            {"Total"} += $PosDetails->{"SalSubTotal"}->[$i];
}
```

Right where I check the length of the array, I get a `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation` warning. It just seems a little odd to get that warning on that line. Why does it show this warning?

Comment: Double-check the line number. You shouldn’t get that warning in the code you posted. Note that perl converts `"foo$bar"` into a concatenation (`"foo" . $bar`), but you don’t have code of that form either.

Comment: Triple checked the line number
`Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 156.` and here it is again `156    if ( @product_access == 1 )` Very weird...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some versions of perl will report some warnings in an elsif clause on the if line.  I'm betting that's the case here.

Comment: You are right! Warning suggests the problem is in the `if` statement while it is in one of the `elsif` Got the correct line number with 5.14.2 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread but incorrect line number with v5.8.5 built for sun4-solaris and also with v5.6.1 built for sun4-solaris-64int. Thanks!